# HQL with join of 3 tables and where condition

Tags: mysql, sql, hibernate, hql

We had a report generating HQL with a join between 2 tables that worked correctly. But with changes with DB design, we need to do the same thing with 3 tables now. But I am not getting the desired results.

Earlier, all users had a single role in the system and that role was part of the user table. In that case the following HQL worked

```
<![CDATA[SELECT new com.test.reportsmodel.agentReport(u, 
            COUNT( t.transactionId ), SUM(CASE 
            WHEN  t.status =  'CREATED' THEN 1 
            WHEN  t.status =  'PAID' THEN 1 
            WHEN  t.status =  'DELIVERED' THEN 1 
            ELSE 0 END )) 
            FROM User AS u
            LEFT JOIN u.transactionsForAgent t WITH  
            (t.invoiceDate BETWEEN :startDate AND :endDate)
            WHERE u.role = 'EXTERNALAGENT'
            GROUP BY u.userId]]>
```

Now the db design has changed that allows users to have multiple roles in the system. Hence useraccess table has been created that has userId and Role in it. To take care of the change the above HQL has been updated as

```
 <![CDATA[SELECT new com.test.reportsmodel.agentReport(u, 
        COUNT( t.transactionId ), SUM(CASE 
        WHEN t.status = 'CREATED' THEN 1 
        WHEN t.status = 'PAID' THEN 1 
        WHEN t.status = 'DELIVERED' THEN 1 
        ELSE 0 END )) 
        FROM User AS u
        LEFT JOIN u.transactionsForAgent t WITH 
        (t.invoiceDate BETWEEN :startDate AND :endDate)
        LEFT JOIN u.useraccesses a WITH 
        (a.role = 'EXTERNALAGENT')
        GROUP BY u.userId]]>
```

But this query is not giving the correct result. There are quite a few HQLs that need modification because of the change in role. I wanted to understand what is the best way to incorporate this change in the HQL.

Comment: In what way is the result wrong?

Comment: @carbontax with the same data and only change in table, the new report has different numbers. I have not done full analysis of no of rows etc.

Comment: You need to do more analysis. Are you getting wrong matches? Duplicate rows? Don't make us guess.

Comment: I could find the issue, the join with useraccesses should be INNER JOIN and not LEFT JOIN for the exact match with role. That change seemed to have resolved the issue.